# Good reduction at all non-archimedean valuations

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am looking for an explicit example (i.e. with an explicit Weierstrass equation given) of an elliptic curve defined over a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ which has good reduction with respect to all non-archimedean valuations (and some argument for why this property holds). Such elliptic curves (up to some caveats which can be ignored here) are the starting point for Mochizuki's IUTT papers.

General methods for obtaining such examples are very welcome, but please accompany such methods with an explicit example.

Comment: Any CM elliptic curve has potentially good reduction everywhere (hence good reduction everywhere over some finite extension), and gives rise to many examples. You can use LMFDB.org (see the list [here](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/?include_base_change=on&include_Q_curves=include&conductor_norm=1&include_isogenous=on&include_cm=include)) to find many more examples.

Comment: Thanks! If someone is able to take some example on the list which is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, and spell out the details (i.e. explain what the non-archimedean valuations are, and explain why we have good reduction at each of them), I'd be happy to accept it as an answer.